# How to hide image based on variable value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to hide image in my HTML page using JavaScript. I have defined a function `hide1()` which is called as soon as page loads using onload in `body` tag. Function `hide1()` checks value of `filename` and based on that it hides image particular tag based on its id. The code is working fine till one of the if function is not satisfied.
For example, it will hide first 2 image if `filename1` and `filename 2` is `null` but if `filename 3` not `null` and again `filename 4` is `null` than it will not hide image 4.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Audit Evidence</title>
</head>
<body onload="hide1()">


<%String filename1 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename1"); %>
<%String filename2 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename2"); %>
<%String filename3 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename3"); %>
<%String filename4 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename4"); %>
<%String filename5 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename5"); %>
<%String filename6 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename6"); %>
<%String filename7 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename7"); %>
<%String filename8 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename8"); %>
<%String filename9 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename9"); %>
<%String filename10 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename10"); %>
<%String filename11 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename11"); %>
<%String filename12 = (String)request.getAttribute("filename12"); %>
<%-- 
<img src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename1%>" ><BR>
<%=filename1%><BR><BR>

<img src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename2%>" ><BR>
<%=filename2%><BR><BR>

<img src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename3%>" ><BR>
<%=filename3%><BR><BR> 

<img id="imgZoom" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename1%>"><BR> --%>

<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename1%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="first image"><img id="filename1" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename1%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"  /></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename2%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="second image"><img id="filename2" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename2%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename3%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="third image"><img id="filename3"  class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename3%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename4%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="fourth image"><img id="filename4" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename4%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename5%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="fifth image"><img id="filename5" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename5%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename6%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="sixth image"><img id="filename6" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename6%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename7%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="seventh image"><img id="filename7" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename7%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename8%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="eighth image"><img id="filename8" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename8%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename9%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="ninth image"><img id="filename9" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename9%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename10%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="tenth image"><img id="filename10" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename10%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename11%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="eleventh image"><img id="filename11" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename11%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>
<a href="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename12%>" data-lightbox="AuditEvidence" data-title="twelveth image"><img id="filename12" class="Evidence" src="/AuditEvidenceImages/<%=filename12%>" alt="" height="150px" width="150px"/></a>


<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>


   function hide1() {


        if (<%=filename1%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename1").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        }


        if (<%=filename2%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename3%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename4%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename4").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename5%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename5").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename6%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename6").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename7%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename7").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename8%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename8").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename9%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename9").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename10%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename10").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename11%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename11").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


        if (<%=filename12%> == null) {
            document.getElementById("filename12").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Filter the elements you want to hide and then execute hide()?

Answer (score 1):

This approach has lot of duplicate code.
You could create an array of fileNames:-

var fileArray = [fileName1, fileName2,...]

Iterate over the array and each for each element call below method:-

```
function setImageVisibility(id) {
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  img.style.visibility = (img == null) ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Or Better

1) Iterate over fileArray

2) If fileName is null - Don't create anchor link

This will reduce the code a lot.